# found some error in setup flutter, how can i solve this?

Tags: flutter, cmd

I setup flutter for app development and vs code is already install in my device. still display this error, how can i solve this error?

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080518/visual-studio-not-installed-this-is-necessary-for-windows-development)

Answer (score 0):

You're fine to build mobile apps, the error is just letting you know that your flutter is not yet configured for desktop app development on windows.

Development on windows needs you to install `Visual Studio` which is different from `Visual Studio Code`.

So you're fine.

If you want to stop the error just go ahead and download and setup  `Visual Studio` for desktop app development.