# flutter doctor ~ VS Code "Desktop Development in C++" error

Tags: c++, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-doctor

The Flutter Doctor is showing this error:

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https:// visualstudio. microsoft .com /downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

I have already installed VS Code. How can I install the workload while not uninstalling and again installing VS Code?

Comment: Ignore this error, if you don't have any future plans for developing Windows Desktop Apps. C++ is required to generate Windows build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080518/visual-studio-not-installed-this-is-necessary-for-windows-development

Comment: You mean this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080518/visual-studio-not-installed-this-is-necessary-for-windows-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) are two different software by the way :)

Comment: Thanks, Now I have downloaded the Visual Studio and the flutter doctor is not giving any error!