# Flutter build app failed Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android, flutter

I received the following error while trying to build flutter app on Android Studio

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :video_compress
```

I tried `flutter clean` `flutter pub cache repair` and also deleting pubspec.lock .. still the problem isn't solved

Here is the result of `flutter doctor`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.819], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.64.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080518/visual-studio-not-installed-this-is-necessary-for-windows-development)

Comment: No I don't think so, I am not developing the app for Windows I am developing it for Android and iOS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by adding this line in the project level build.gradle thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726436/13691187)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" } //Added this line
    }
}
```

Another solution that also worked for me but uses jcenter() which apparently reached end of service

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() //instead of mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

apparently it's gradle servers problem but not sure if this is the best solution, however it worked for me.